# Saving contents of one textarea in another

Tags: jquery, forms, textarea

I have a simple form, where the user text into various fields, and the results are summarized within a textarea (#1) on button click.

I have also added an `<input type=reset>` to clear the form and 1st textarea.

I would like to add a second textarea that sequentially "saves" the items from the first textarea, after each click, preferably in a numeric list. Seems easy to do, but I can only get as far as replicating the two textareas using javascript.

I'd appreciate any help with this!

HTML

```
<input id="bl_pct" size="5" value="0" type="text"><br>
<input id="seg_pct" size="5" value="0" type="text"><br>
<input id="lym_pct" size="5" value="0" type="text"><br>
<div class="textoutput">
    <form>
        <input id="print" value="Click to print " type="button"><br>
        <textarea id="diffOut" rows="5" cols="60"></textarea>
        <input class="btn" type="reset" value="Reset the counter"><br>
    </form>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('#print').on('click', function (){
  // setting field variables
    var blst = $('#bl_pct').val();
    var seg = $('#seg_pct').val();
    var lym = $('#lym_pct').val();
    var Str = 'Output here: '+blst+' ; '+seg+' ; '+lym+'.';
    $('#diffOut').val(Str);
 });
```

Here's a fiddle to this: http://jsfiddle.net/sZYYK/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this to the end of your click event

```
$('#diffHist').val($('#diffHist').val() + Str + '\n');
```

will add to whatever 'diffHist' contains, adding the current Str value and a newline '\n'.

If you want to number the lines then create a variable and increment it each time, appending it to the text in a similar way (using +).

If you want the lines in reverse order then use:

```
$('#diffHist').val(Str + '\n' + $('#diffHist').val());
```

Using a counter to number the entries:

```
$('#print').on('click', function (){
  // setting global field variables
    this.counter = this.counter || 0;
    this.counter++;
    var blst = $('#bl_pct').val();
    var seg = $('#seg_pct').val();
    var lym = $('#lym_pct').val();
    var Str = 'Output here: '+blst+' ; '+seg+' ; '+lym+'.';
    $('#diffOut').val(Str);
    $('#diffHist').val($('#diffHist').val() + this.counter + ' ' + Str + '\n');
 });
```

BTW Those variables aren't global so you might edit the comment; they are local variables. (`counter` isn't a local variable, it is a property attached to the input element.)

Comment: Great! Thanks for the detailed explanation of the steps, it really helps a novice like me learn.